# requiring child process is coming as empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

When I use

```
 var childprocess = require('child_process');
```

its always coming as blank.When I do something as

```
 var childProcess1 = require('child_process').spawn;
```

its undefined and ,

```
var childProcess2 = require('child_process').spawn();
```

is giving that it does not have spawn function.

Node version v0.12.7

Comment: What version of node are you on?

Comment: Node version is v0.12.7

Comment: I cannot reproduce then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your child process has nothing to execute, hence blank.
I guess what you are trying to do is this

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
//I'm just checking the node version installed, you can do your own process here
exec('node -v', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
if (error !== null) {
    console.log('exec error: ' + error);
}
});
```

Comment: I tried this but I am getting this error 'exec is not a function'

Comment: Need more info about your code and setup. Also do paste a bit more of your error stacktrace.

Comment: I am using browserify , in my index.js I included the above code when I create the bundle then in the browser i get this error 'Uncaught TypeError: require(...).exec is not a function'